# The difference between st2 and st3 about on_query_completions

Tags: python, sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I want to show the auto-completion panel,and I successed in sublime-text 3 using the API on_query_completions,but I failed in sublime-text2 using the same code.

The code:

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin

class CCAutoComplete(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
     def on_query_completions(self, view, prefix, locations):
        flag = sublime.INHIBIT_WORD_COMPLETIONS | sublime.INHIBIT_EXPLICIT_COMPLETIONS
        result = ([["abv","abv"],["abcd123","abcd"]],flag)
        return result
```

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console? Have you tried sending the 2D array without flags?

Comment: Also, try using tuples instead of arrays. `[("abv","abv"),("abcd123","abcd")]`. That is what I use in my upcoming [**CustomCompletions**](https://forum.sublimetext.com/uploads/default/original/3X/5/d/5ddc69fc0d6ea71b0a30156da7a1e94f7ceec905.gif) release, although I haven't tested it in ST2.

Comment: I try using tuples instead of arrays. [("abv","abv"),("abcd123","abcd")]. And I successed!Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an array of tuples for the completion values instead of a 2D-array:

`[("abv","abv"),("abcd123","abcd")]`